# Recommended way to pass data from activity to viewPager fragment

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity that performs network operation, and on success, it needs to send data to `view pager fragment`.

So this is my structure.

> Activity -> Home Fragment -> ViewPager [Fragment#1, Fragment#2]

Now the issue is that i can send data from `Activity` to `Home Fragment`, but i am unable to send data to `View Pager Fragment`, as activity does not have any direct connection with it.

To Fix this, I have taken network call from activity to fragment, and once i get response from `service call`, i pass data to `viewPager` fragment from  `Home Fragment`.

This is working fine, and giving me desired result, but i am little confused if this is the right approach.

or there is some other recommended approach available that i can use, and pass data from activity to child fragment, or view Pager fragment, whose reference is not directly available to activity.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at the new Android Architecture Components, specifically `ViewModel` and `LiveData`. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in
>   a lifecycle conscious way.

You can create a shared view model that can be accessed by the activity and any fragment in that activity.

Example from the link:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}


public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(this, item -> {
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

> Notice that both fragments use getActivity() when getting the
>   ViewModelProvider. As a result, both fragments receive the same
>   SharedViewModel instance, which is scoped to the activity.

For your example, this avoids passing data down the hierarchy from activity to fragment then child fragment, they can all reference `SharedViewModel`.